# When do I call filepicker.setKey() if loading filepicker.io JavaScript in a non-blocking fashion?

Tags: filepicker.io

If you do it too early, you get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: filepicker is not defined`.

I'm using this code from https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/ to load it:

```
For advanced users, if you want to load the javascript in a non-blocking fashion, you can use this instead:

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(a){if(window.filepicker){return}var b=a.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=!0;b.src=("https:"===a.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+"//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js";var c=a.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c);var d={};d._queue=[];var e="pick,pickMultiple,pickAndStore,read,write,writeUrl,export,convert,store,storeUrl,remove,stat,setKey,constructWidget,makeDropPane".split(",");var f=function(a,b){return function(){b.push([a,arguments])}};for(var g=0;g<e.length;g++){d[e[g]]=f(e[g],d._queue)}window.filepicker=d})(document); 
</script>
```

I can't figure out how to know when it is loaded so that I can call filepicker.setKey(). A work-around is to call it every time I use the filepicker, but that seems lame.

Comment: Why I cannot fine the filepicker now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-blocking js queues up all calls while the script loads, and then executes those calls once the script has loaded. You should be able to start making calls immediately after including the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(a){if(window.filepicker){return}var b=a.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=!0;b.src=("https:"===a.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+"//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js";var c=a.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c);var d={};d._queue=[];var e="pick,pickMultiple,pickAndStore,read,write,writeUrl,export,convert,store,storeUrl,remove,stat,setKey,constructWidget,makeDropPane".split(",");var f=function(a,b){return function(){b.push([a,arguments])}};for(var g=0;g<e.length;g++){d[e[g]]=f(e[g],d._queue)}window.filepicker=d})(document); </script>
<script>
filepicker.setKey('testing');
filepicker.pick()
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbcbK/1/

Comment: Ah, thanks that works, and it's nice to know what that block of JS does too!

Comment: What doesn't work is putting the script tag before the closing body tag (for both the blocking and non-blocking JS): `Copy and paste this script into your page just before the </body> tag.`. This results in my page being reloaded when I call `pickAndStore`, but I'm not going to worry about why that happens now.

Comment: For future viewers, I don't think there's any issue with putting the loader script right before the </body> tag and it certainly shouldn't reload the page. I even load the async script with an async loader after the page has loaded. Just make sure you execute the loader script before you try and use it.